# Drupal text format ( input/output filter) issue

Tags: drupal

I am running drupal 7. I get ckeditor installed. am using full html as text input in filter option.

Am facing some problems with the output. This is specially for

html element.

There is no line break between to paragraph !
E.G: this code:
`<p> my text par one </p><p>my text par two</p>`

output :
 my text par one my text par two
(IN A SINGLE LIGN !)

I would like to get linbreak on each paragraph as we can expect it from any html code.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add required HTML tags under filter which you are using.

URL :- `admin/config/content/formats/full_html`

Also on same page check **Enabled filters** configuration.

- Display any HTML as plain text - unchecked
- List item Convert line breaks into HTML - checked

Cheers!!!